# Optimising Google Scripts Function - Finding Last Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've cobbled together a script for google scripts, to use in Google sheets, which aims to find certain rows and move them about.

When a check box in a certain column is marked, I get a range of cells from that row, and then move them to another column. I want them to go to the last empty row in that column. Or, if it's easier, they could go to the first empty row.

I have the functionality in place, but I'm worried that once my sheet gets to a hundred or a few hundred rows, this function is going to run incredibly slowly.

Can anyone help me to write this code in a more optimised/efficient way?

Edit: I need the last from from a specific subset of columns, not just the last row in the whole sheet.

Code is below:

```
function moveDoneTask()
{

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 var columnNumberToWatch = 7;
 var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

 var lastRowinProgressColumns; 
 var lastRowinDoneColumns = 0;

 for (var i=1, doneRows=sheet.getRange("K:S").getNumRows(); i<=doneRows; i++) {
    if ( !sheet.getRange(i, 11, 1, 9).isBlank() ) 
    {
      lastRowinDoneColumns = i;
      Logger.log("last done row" +lastRowinDoneColumns);
    }
  }

  for (var j=1, notDoneRows=sheet.getRange("A:I").getNumRows(); j<=notDoneRows; j++) {
    if (!sheet.getRange(j, 1, 1, 9).isBlank()) 
    {
      lastRowinProgressColumns = j;
      Logger.log("last not done row" +lastRowinProgressColumns);
    }
  }

 if (range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.isChecked()) 
 {
   Logger.log("is checked");

   targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRowinDoneColumns + 1, 11)
   cellsToMove = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 9)
   belowCellsToMove = cellsToMove.offset(1, 0) //get the row of cells below the cells that are about to be moved
   rangeMovingUp = sheet.getRange("A"+belowCellsToMove.getRow()+":I"+lastRowinProgressColumns)

   Logger.log("row below me is row " + belowCellsToMove.getRow());

   cellsToMove.moveTo(targetRange);
   rangeMovingUp.moveTo(cellsToMove);

 }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit 2: Took the advice below and made some changes to the script, seems to be running faster now:

```
function moveDoneTask()
{
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
 var columnNumberToWatch = 7;
 var range = sheet.getActiveCell(); 

 if (range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.isChecked()) 
 {
   targetRow = (sheet.getRange('M11:S').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1);
   targetRange = sheet.getRange(targetRow, 11)
   notDoneRows = sheet.getRange("A:I").getNumRows()
   cellsToMove = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 9)
   belowCellsToMove = cellsToMove.offset(1, 0)
   rangeMovingUp = sheet.getRange("A"+belowCellsToMove.getRow()+":I"+notDoneRows)

   cellsToMove.moveTo(targetRange);
   rangeMovingUp.moveTo(cellsToMove);
 }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see the sheet, or an example, to fully understand but you can do `lastRow = sheet.getLastrow()` to get the last used row in the sheet (so you'd need to paste to `lastRow + 1`

Comment: I originally wanted to use ```.getLastRow()``` but I need the last row in a specific column(s), not the last row in the whole sheet. So I'm looking to move say cells A10, B10, C10 and D10 to columns E, F, G and H, but to an empty row within those columns only. It's basically a to do list, so I'm moving a done task from one side of the spreadsheet to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A possibility to get the last row of a certain column is to use [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getNextDataCell(Direction)). This returns you the next cell on the edge to a empty range (which is equivalent to the first empty row if you do not have blank cells inbetween). Mind that there is a documentation bug, the correct syntax is:
  `var lastRowinProgressColumns=sheet.getRange(1, 11).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();`
- To make the code more efficient, check first either the active range is in the correct column (`if (range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.isChecked())`), and retrieve `lastRowinProgressColumns` within the `if` statement (there is no reason to retrieve it if the codition is not fulfilled).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This helped a lot. I realised I still need do need to get the last empty row, but I think I was able to optimise it a little anyway. I'll post my new code below...

Comment: You optimized code looks much better.  Just `notDoneRows=sheet.getRange("A:I").getNumRows();` within the `for` loop is out of place (should be before the `for` loop). Also, I do not understand why you loop through all rows from 1 to `notDoneRows` checking if those rows are not empty (`if (!sheet.getRange(j, 1, 1, 9).isBlank()) `) - how can those rows be empty if they come before `notDoneRows`?

Comment: If you modified your code / question, for visibility reasons I recommend you to edit your original question and add the modified version at the end of the question as "update" rather than posting it as an answer, especially if this modification does not completely solve your issue yet.

Comment: Thanks, made more changes, sorry this time I'll edit my original post rather than adding an answer. I think I've optimised it as much as I can, it's certainly a lot shorter and after some quick testing it's running faster by a couple of seconds!

Answer (score 0):

New slightly optimised code:

```
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 var columnNumberToWatch = 7;
 var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

 var targetRow;
 var lastRowinProgressColumns = 0;

 if (range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.isChecked()) 
 {
   targetRow = (sheet.getRange('L3:S').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1);
   targetRange = sheet.getRange(targetRow, 11)

     for (var j=1, notDoneRows=sheet.getRange("A:I").getNumRows(); j<=notDoneRows; j++) {
    if (!sheet.getRange(j, 1, 1, 9).isBlank()) 
    {
      lastRowinProgressColumns = j;
      Logger.log("last not done row" +lastRowinProgressColumns);
    }
  }
   cellsToMove = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 9)
   belowCellsToMove = cellsToMove.offset(1, 0)
   rangeMovingUp = sheet.getRange("A"+belowCellsToMove.getRow()+":I"+lastRowinProgressColumns)

   cellsToMove.moveTo(targetRange);
   rangeMovingUp.moveTo(cellsToMove);
 }
}
```